# Regex html help needed

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an HTML response body/string. Part of that html content are these strings -

```
<h2><a href="javascript:;" class="user-name-class">MY_USER_NAME<b></b></a></h2>

["media_detail","init",[false,"",null,true,1,4,"99999_XXXXX_99999",11836530,"00076f7474727febc37a8825d373a5be","\/p\/LdvJWSF-6b\/","\/accounts\/login\/"]],
```

From these I need to extract `MY_USER_NAME` and `99999_XXXXX_99999`

I would appreciate help from regex rockstars. This is in ruby 1.9.3. Thanks.

UPDATE: We are using regex because this is not done in realtime, so performance is not a concern.

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for this. Use an HTML/XML parser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: This is not a question of performance. Regular expressions are simply **unable to** parse HTML correctly. Not even speaking of invalid HTML that could be taken care of by a DOM parser.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is HTML so you should parse it with HTML and another is JSON, so you could use some JSON library. Don't use regex. [It's evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use HTML/JSON libraries, you can get the first one with:

```
str.gsub!(/<.*?>/, '')
```

To regex the second one you're going to have to tell us more about the format of the string...  what's consistent, what isn't, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
s.split(/"user-name-class">/)[1].split(/</)[0]
```

(see [this demo](http://ideone.com/U1yL9g))

and

```
s.split(/\["media_detail"/)[1].split(/\[/)[1].split(/"?,"?/)[6]
```

(see [this demo](http://ideone.com/bm2FQk))

Comment: So I have this big HTML body/string, how do I apply this regex to the whole html content?

Comment: @user310525 - Just put the entire html content to string `s`. Did you check demo links?

Comment: I get this error -undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass. This is what I tried - html_body.split(/"user-name-class">/)[1].split(/</)[0]

Comment: @user310525 - You got that error, because first `split(/"user-name-class">/)` failed, so there is no `[1]` element, which means your string `html_body` does not contain **"user-name-class">** inside of it. Print your `html_body` and you will see...

Comment: Sorry false alarm, yea that works. Also is there a way to avoid using methods split & []. I was hoping to avoid nil errors, in case the pattern changes.